How to configure Jetty Server v12 to serve CSS and Javascript files
This is a followup question to my earlier question 
The CSS file does not get loaded if I configure like this in the html files.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" type="text/css">

or
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">

While Edge and Chrome show no errors at all, Firefox shows this error message:
The stylesheet http://localhost:8080/app/main.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.

In the Handler this is how the response header is set:
response.setStatus(200);
response.getHeaders().put(HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypes.Type.TEXT_HTML_UTF_8.toString());
Content.Sink.write(response, true, msg, callback);
callback.succeeded();
return true;

My question is: How to configure Jetty Server v12 to serve CSS and Javascript files?
Thanks in advance.

You can easily setup a Jetty ResourceHandler to serve the static files from a url-path and base-resource that you want.
In brief, it will look like this ...
String resourceRoot = // URI string to root of resources
ResourceFactory resourceFactory = ResourceFactory.of(server);
ResourceHandler handler = new ResourceHandler();
handler.setBaseResource(resourceFactory.newResource(resourcesRoot));
handler.setDirAllowed(true);

handlers.addHandler(handler);

The resourceRoot can be a file-system, a classloader reference, or generally any URL that java supports as well.
The ResourceHandler can be on it's own, or under a ContextHandler, or even part of a handler wrapper or selection handler (like a PathMappingsHandler).
For complete examples of this, see the jetty-examples project.

Jetty Core File Server using ResourceHandler - https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples/tree/12.0.x/embedded/file-server
Jetty EE10 Servlet Environment File Server using DefaultServlet - https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples/tree/12.0.x/embedded/ee10-file-server
Jetty Core PathMappingsHandler with ResourceHandler - https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples/tree/12.0.x/embedded/path-mapping-handler


thanks that was useful. I had to rewire a bit.
however every now and then the CSS file doesn't get loaded. here are the error messages that I see:
Firefox:
Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content.
Chrome:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
Edge:
GET http://localhost:8080/app/index net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
If this is because of wrong configuration, the error should happen for every request.
So server side rendering of dynamic content has it's own problems like this.

an update to my previous comment. when I replaced Freemarker with Thymeleaf, I did not see the above CSS loading issue. may be the way I am using Freemarker has an issue. but for now, things seems to be working fine in all aspects. thanks for your timely help.
